# Start up program file load error

Tags: c#

I've reate a program, and I put in the programone system to statup with windows... using this idea: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial151_Run-the-application-at-Windows-startup.html

But, when the program is started... I recive one message error, when this eror say: it's impossible to load file: start.ini

so, when the system start the program, the program is loaded in C:\windows\system32, becaouse this, the file of my program not is loaded...

to load the file, I use this command to get the file directory: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data\\start.ini"`

But, how I can load this file, in this case ?

Comment: Try `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` instead of `GetCurrentDirectory()`

Answer (score 0):

You can save the path to start.ini file to the Registery, and read it on startup. See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

p.s. the other way is to put a link to you app into the Autorun  folder.